# Python static methods in class without state

Tags: python, oop, private, static-classes

I'm writing a message parser class. There is one main static method which calls many other (private) methods. Class doesn't have any state, I use it to have context. Code:

```
class MessageParser:

    @staticmethod
    def check_errors(msg):
        _check_error_1(msg)
        _check_error_2(msg)
        ...

def _check_error_1(log):
    ...

def _check_error_2(log):
    ...

...
```

My question is: what is the best way to write something like that. Should `_check_error_x` methods be contained in LogParser class and made private static (I know there is no real privacy in Python), and `check_errors` @classmethod? Or defining them outside class is a good solution?

Comment: Why have a class *at all*? Just put those functions in a module if all you want is context (a namespace).

Comment: Note: you can still choose what to expose using `__all__` (modules).